# Why doesn't VoIP gateway send any media and breaks the call?

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, pjsip, sdp

I have a problem when connecting to Bodhicom 3408 P/O VoIP/FXO gateway using PJSUA test application. When I use CSipSimple Android application (https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple), everything is fine. When I use PJSUA test application, the gateway doesn't send to me any RTP packets and breaks the call as soon as I ACK it. I spent quite a lot of time looking at captured network packets between the gateway and the Android device, comparing that to the packets exchanged by the gateway and the PC. Yet I found nothing that could tell me why the gateway behaves in a different way. I think that the problem lies in the INVITE request since in case of Android it is responded with 100 Trying, then 183 Session in progress and a stream of RTP packets. In case of PC there is 100 Trying and 183 Session in progress as well but no incoming RTP packets.

Below is an INVITE request that comes from Android (works):

```
INVITE sip:701203@10.17.17.2 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.17.17.119:60114;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjd4I9mLGfdc-dHLeftgDhnB1QSKTwfp8L
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "adam" <sip:11@10.17.17.119>;tag=.SLc6umpZHvQ8xLhKzIPyarZFGIFKcYa
To: <sip:701203@10.17.17.2>
Contact: "adam" <sip:11@10.17.17.119:60114;ob>
Call-ID: VJnv1gCnGacB5plPReyxB-arbWy.zB1W
CSeq: 695 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: CSipSimple_android_x86_64-25/r2457
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   364

v=0
o=- 3830333691 3830333691 IN IP4 10.17.17.119
s=pjmedia
c=IN IP4 10.17.17.119
t=0 0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 9 99 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 10.17.17.119
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 10.17.17.119
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:99 SILK/24000
a=fmtp:99 useinbandfec=0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
```

and an INVITE request from PC (doesn't work):

```
INVITE sip:701203@10.17.17.2 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.17.17.134:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjEwTCSQN5M8KFw5Jrg9OPaA.7EnsKdhSq
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:11@10.17.17.134;tag=z3RNgXnVH5JEsCH09YXKFNb5sj1kBGRv
To: sip:701203@10.17.17.2
Contact: <sip:11@10.17.17.134:5060;ob>
Call-ID: AaWE5-53WQNrpgixujOluli7jbVEmeQM
CSeq: 19571 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.10 Linux-5.8.0.53/x86_64/glibc-2.32
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   629

v=0
o=- 3830332754 3830332754 IN IP4 10.17.17.134
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4002 RTP/AVP 96 97 98 99 3 0 8 9 120 121 122
c=IN IP4 10.17.17.134
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4003 IN IP4 10.17.17.134
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:98 speex/32000
a=rtpmap:99 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:99 mode=30
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:120 telephone-event/16000
a=fmtp:120 0-16
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=rtpmap:122 telephone-event/32000
a=fmtp:122 0-16
a=ssrc:1692601373 cname:3065339d70665017
```

The IP addresses and the AORs above are used in isolated, test network only. I didn't remove them on purpose.

I guess it would be much easier if I could get some feedback information from the gateway. Unfortunately I can't find any detailed infomation/logs in the gateway UI. The manufacturer doesn't reply to my questions also.

Answer (score 1):

> But the gateway should not continue the call (for a few seconds) but
> without the audio stream. Am I right?

Yes, it is a QOS precondition where the session establishment is suspended :

```
While session establishment is suspended, user agents SHOULD not
send any data over any media stream.  In the case of RTP, neither
RTP nor RTCP packets are sent.
```

> Maybe 84kb/s or 64kb/s is too small?

The SDP is maybe not compliant with older user-agents with these two *different* b fields ; one at session level and the other at the media level.
b=AS:84 at the session level means that the bandwidth for all streams is 84 Kbps  including IP/UDP/RTP overhead and b=TIAS:64000 at the audio media level a maximum of 64 Kbps(so 84 with overhead is ok I expect) ;

> It is recommended that the AS bandwidth specifier be used at the
> session level
> for backward compatibility and also at media level, both for audio and video,
> for compatibility with multi-media telephony services over IMS.

3GPP TS 26.114 “IP Multimedia System (IMS); Multimedia Telephony;
media handling and interaction”

So you could try :

```
v=0 
o=- 3830332754 3830332754 IN IP4 10.17.17.134 
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
b=TIAS:64000 
t=0 0 
a=X-nat:0 
m=audio 4002 RTP/AVP 96 97 98 99 3 0 8 9 120 121 122 c=IN IP4 10.17.17.134
b=AS:84
b=TIAS:64000
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will have to find a way to manually modify the outgoing SDP. In order to remove the bandwidth information entirely, I used a ready to use configuration option of the library.

Answer (score 0):

When I modified the PJSUA test application source code not to include the bandwidth information, it started working:

```
b=AS:84
b=TIAS:64000
```

So now the INVITE request looks like this and this works:

```
INVITE sip:701203@10.17.17.2 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.17.17.134:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjAxGfIo8mYgfV2.OtyQNXne6jFEoHSl7J
Max-Forwards: 70
From: sip:11@10.17.17.134;tag=qo67aAphq-cgXXWYCX8RjvTR2rZxB2Wu
To: sip:701203@10.17.17.2
Contact: <sip:11@10.17.17.134:5060;ob>
Call-ID: C0Sf-v8BBaINSE.8j-8BsWgsPponNb2h
CSeq: 520 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Session-Expires: 1800
Min-SE: 90
User-Agent: PJSUA v2.10 Linux-5.8.0.53/x86_64/glibc-2.32
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   606

v=0
o=- 3830404967 3830404967 IN IP4 10.17.17.134
s=pjmedia
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 96 97 98 99 3 0 8 9 120 121 122
c=IN IP4 10.17.17.134
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 10.17.17.134
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:96 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:98 speex/32000
a=rtpmap:99 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:99 mode=30
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:120 telephone-event/16000
a=fmtp:120 0-16
a=rtpmap:121 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:121 0-16
a=rtpmap:122 telephone-event/32000
a=fmtp:122 0-16
a=ssrc:1942999776 cname:053aa66259195378
```

However I am not 100% sure whether it's the gateway's fault of the client's. Maybe 84kb/s or 64kb/s is too small? If I understand correctly, it's the declaration of the sender. The gateway is entitled to break the call if it thinks that's too much to handle. But the gateway should not continue the call (for a few seconds) but without the audio stream. Am I right? I'm happy I solved the issue but I would be very thankful if somebody explained to me why the gateway behaves this way.